# transparent background on scrollbar track

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I have a div with lines to separate different sections, with a scrollbar on the x axis. I have a feature so that when the user hovers over the div, the scrollbar thumb shows. However, the scrollbar track leaves a white line across the bottom of the div. I tried `background: none;` and setting the background to a transparent image. Is there any way to fix this?

code sand box: https://codesandbox.io/s/festive-hermann-xejx0?file=/src/App.js

Comment: insert your html and the logic for the appearance of the scrollbar

Answer (score 1):

```
div::-webkit-scrollbar{ background: 0}
div:hover::-webkit-scrollbar{ background: #aaa; height: 25px }
div:hover::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb{ background: #fff; border-radius: 10px}
```

Unfortunately, css is inconsistent and "0" cannot be replaced with "none".

It is `-webkit-` It has only partial [support](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-scrollbar), for chrome and Opera works, for IF and FF (which I can't test right now) you may add without any prefix

```
div::scrollbar{ background: 0}
```

After all, it will look different on different devices - as always with limited support. You can do your best for supported browsers, but one always comes out with a white bar (which isn't ugliest thing in the world).

I'm afraid there's nothing else to do with `css`. I don't use js so I won't start to reinvent the syntax, especially since I'm not sure if the scrollbar track is reachable by `js`.

If you are very determined there are always some CSS tricks like - add a curtain with `position: relative; bottom: 10px` or maybe a very funky box-shadow, but I think it's not a good practice, but rather a headache ...
Maybe - this dark filter should be darker from the bottom?

Comment: unfortunately, adding `background: 0` doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because a div cannot have both

```
 overflow-y: visible;
 overflow-x: scroll;
```

overflow-y gets changed to auto. Therefore the vertical lines cannot overflow outside of the div vertically.
Its also not recommendable to use ::-webkit-scrollbar as it has poor compatibility.
As you are using react, you should instead look at using a Progress bar on scroll component.

Comment: I don't care about `overflow-y`, only `overflow-x` because the white bar shows up